# pthreads arguments issue

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am using pthread for multithreading in my application as:

```
pthread_create(&id1, NULL, &RecvMessageManager::test, args);
```

`args` is basically a structure consisting an instance of another object and callback reference as:

```
struct Args {

    Obj * msgObj;
    void (*callBack)(std::string& header, std::string& payload);
};
```

using the `msgObj`, I am calling one of its methods continuously within a while loop. First time method is getting called, but in the next loop the `msgObj` is becoming null.

Why is this ?

### EDIT

The construction of the instance within the thread

```
    struct Args * args = (struct Args *)val;
    this -> msgObj = args -> msgObj;
    this -> callBack = args -> callBack;
    RecvMessageManager * thisObj = args -> thisObj;
```

Comment: How and where is the `Args` instance constructed? Can you post more code? Also, the callback signature is incorrect if it is a member of function of `Obj`. Should be `void (Obj::* callback)(std::string& header, std::string& payload);`

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @hmjd Thanks for that input. I have updated the code you have asked for. I am correct with reconstructing the instance of `Args`.

Comment: Thank you all. I got the answer. I was reconstructing the `struct Args` properly. But the problem was, I was assigning them to the global variable which later was being accessed with in the thread. Just assigning them to local variables solved the problem. In the code shown above I changed `msgObj` to local variable.